# Save generated xls file temporary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I am trying to save generated xls file temporary in my rails application, to use if for amazon s3 upload.

this is the main method:

```
def index
    @users = User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xls {
        xls  = @users.to_xls
        file = Tempfile.new("temp.xls")
        file.write(xls)

      }
    end
  end
```

when I type ls.class I get String, 
so how can I convert it to object and save it temporary, to pass it s3 method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS-SDK to upload to s3 & then render the link. something like this

```
  def index
    @users = User.all
    xls = @users.to_xls
    render text: upload_to_s3(xls)
  end

  def upload_to_s3(content)
   s3_file = AWS::S3.new.buckets['bucket_name'].objects["temp.xls"].write(content)
    url = s3_file.url_for( :get,
                      expires: 7.days.from_now,
                      secure: true,
                      response_content_disposition: s3_file)
  end
```

Ideally, `upload_to_s3` method should be moved into model as controller should be skinny.

Comment: I think that you have some syntax errors, and also i get the error, "string contains null byte"

Comment: need more details to be able to help you. Can you share the code & error?